# Unix recursive listing only of complete path of files

Tags: unix, command-line, directory

I have a set of directories with files and I want to get a clean list of the absolute paths of all the files in these directories, something like this
Having

```
\home\me\DirA\
          fileA
          fileB
          some_directory_that_i_dont_want_listed

\home\me\DirB\
          fileB
          fileC
```

....
    \home\me\DirXYZ\
              fileOPQ

and get

```
\home\me\DirA\fileA
\home\me\DirA\fileB
\home\me\DirB\fileB
\home\me\DirXYZ\fileOPQ
```

Is this possible with a ls command?, I've tried ls with -R but it lists only the filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case it's of use to anyone, it's simple

```
find /home/me
```

lists everything with absolute paths.

If you need to filter a specific extension

```
find /home/me -name *.someExt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
$ find /home/me/Dir[AB]
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Didn't think of find. But what I needed is a more generic thing (not only for DirA and DirB but your answer gives me ideas to investigate. I will edit the example to make it more clear.